# Give an example of a function which is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$ and not differentiable at the end points.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The question is

> Give an example of a function which is continuous on $[0,1]$, differentiable on $(0,1)$ and not differentiable at the end points.  Justify your answer.

Please give me the function with justification.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$. Half a circle. The tangent lines at the endpoints are orthogonal to the $x$-axis.

Comment: Similarly $\sqrt{\sin \frac x\pi}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt{x(1-x)}$

Like 
$\sqrt{x}$
but symmetric.

Note that
$(x^{1/2})'
=\frac12 x^{-1/2}
$
so the derivative
at $0$ does not exist.